# Principles of putting views into the same design document in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

When creating views in CouchDB, how do you guys determine which design document to use for newly created views? That is, by what principles to determine if 2 or more views are put into the same design document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, the following things happen.

1. When CouchDB needs to update a view with new data, it will update *all views in a design document at the same time*, as an optimization.
2. If you change **anything** inside the design document `views` space (even changing whitespace or comments in your Javascript), CouchDB will **discard the old index and rebuild the view from scratch**.
3. Every update in a database must pass *all* `validate_doc_update()` functions from *all* design documents in the database.

For these reasons, it's best to consider one design document as one application.

One exception I personally use is a `_design/couchdb` document which has common views such as showing me all document conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with couch but in general, it's a good idea to map an application to a design document. So, if you have a database `foo` accessed by an application `bar`, you'd have a `bar` design document inside `foo` which will contain all the views with that `bar` will need each named according to what they serve.

[The guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/design.html) contains some information how to put design documents in the right places.